# travis-ci why the build-passing icon is not set to green upon build ok

Tags: travis-ci

all my tests passed and the building icons still grey (error) ...

[my travis project](https://travis-ci.org/erwin16/Pomodoro)

[image: screen shot]

But the icon ( url pasted) on Github ReadMe is passing/green ...[image]

any missing parameter in the travis.yml ?

```
    {
      "language": "node_js",
      "node_js": "8.4.0",
      "sudo": false,
      "dist": "trusty",
      "addons": {
        "chrome": "stable"
      },
      "cache": {
        "yarn": true,
        "directories": [
          "node_modules"
        ]
      },
      "install": [
        "yarn"
      ],
      "script": [
        "yarn test"
      ],
      "group": "stable",
      "os": "linux"
    }
```

Comment: Try reloading the page.

Comment: already did it ... build is ok, but no change in the icon ...
 https://travis-ci.org/erwin16/Pomodoro/builds/287844171 ..

Comment: seems to be solved now after the last rebuild ...  thanks